# How to configure 'Remove Prefix" in Jenkins Publish over ssh plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh

When ever I run a build in jenkins, after the build is complete the files are deployed to a server via the Publish Over SSH Plugin. I am trying to remove a certain file from being deployed but I have not being able to do that with the 'Remove Prefix' field. Please how do I set the Remove Prefix.

[Image of my Publish over ssh configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntTUa.png)

Comment: Hi Ayotunde, can you provide your current code? AFIK publish over ssh has no support for pipeline yet https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27963

Comment: I just specified the folder in which the file is which is config/

Comment: Yes, sorry I was looking into wrong labels :D you don't use pipeline here of course. Do you get an option with the step itself in configuration? Like http://www.nailedtothex.org/articles-img/jenkins/sshdeploy/config2.png

Comment: @BlazejChecinski No I don't. What I have in my Source Files field is **/*, the Remote Directory field is 'the root directory on the server I am deploying to' while I do not have anything in Exec command and Remove prefix fields yet as I do not know how to configure that aspect yet.

Comment: @BlazejChecinski I just added an image of my Publish over ssh configuration for now.

Comment: I think you are looking into wrong option. Remove prefix (if I understood the manual correctly) will just remove a particular part of path from your sources. Can you go to "advanced" and look up "exclude" input? It should use an ant pattern.

Comment: Solved! I added **/config/db.php to the 'Exclude files' field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added **/config/db.php to the 'Exclude files' field according to @Blazej Checinski. The field can be found when you click on Advanced button.

I used  **/config/db.php because my source files is **/*. The last asterisk ensures that all the files in your project root are copied to the server. config/db.php specifies the file I don't want to deploy.